# How to enable 5GHz WiFi on Edimax AC600

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I've purchased an Edimax AC600 Dual-Band Wi-Fi USB Adapter for my Ubuntu 18.04 PC. It did not work out of the box, and I saw advice out on the Internet on how to obtain the driver source code and install it, but I learned that a driver for this adapter is also available in Ubuntu through `rtl8812au-dkms` package. I installed the package by running

```
apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

The adapter started working after installing the driver, but I cannot see any 5GHz WiFi networks on the PC. My laptop and phone can connect to my 5GHz network just fine, so the problem must be with the PC. If you had experience using this adapter, please let me know how did you make it see the 5GHz networks.

UPD1:

Upon heynnema's request I listed the avaliable frequencies and saw some 5GHz frequencies there:

```
dmytro@dkpc1:~$ iwlist wlx74da38eea053 freq
wlx74da38eea053  21 channels in total; available frequencies :
          ... [removed] ...
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
```

After this I inspected my router settings and found out that channel selection for 5GHz WiFi was set to automatic, and the channel 169 was selected. I changed it manually to channel 64. After this I was able to see the network from my PC and connect to it. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and show us `iwlist wlan0 freq` and `dkms status` and `cat /etc/modprobe.d/*8812*` (if it exists). What channel is the 5ghz wireless network set to in your router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in Canada and it seems like this adapter only ever works on non-DFS 5Ghz channels even though "iw phy phy0 channels" lists all the 5Ghz channels being available. In my case I have to manually select from 36, 40, 44, 48, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165 for 20Mhz width and the list of available channels shrinks for 40 and 80Mhz. Tested it in Windows 10 and got similar results.